# Access to props inside javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I just start to learn vuejs 2 but I have an issue, I'm passing a props to a child component like this :

```
<div class="user">
  <h3>{{ user.name }}</h3>
  <depenses :user-id="user.id"></depenses>
</div>
```

And here is how I use it in my child component :

```
export default {
  name: 'depenses',
  props: ['userId'],
  data () {
    return {
      depenses: []
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.getDepenses()
  },
  methods: {
    getDepenses: function () {
      this.$http.get('myurl' + this.userId).then(response => {
        this.depenses = response.body
        this.haveDepenses = true
      }, response => {
        console.log('Error with getDepenses')
      })
    }
  }
}
```

`this.userId` is undefined but I'm able to display it with `<span>{{ userId }}</span>` and I can see in the vuejs console the param userId with the value

Why I have an undefined value in the js ?

Comment: How is `user.id` being populated in the parent component, is it being populated async way?

Comment: @Saurabh Yes, I get my user with a $http.get()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found why I couldn't get my value, thanks to @Saurabh comment, he reminds me that I get my props from an async way, so I had to set a watcher when my props change, like this :

```
  watch: {
    userId: function () {
      this.getDepenses()
    }
  },
```